# OWA Font size changes after a user hits Enter

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-web-app

Our users are reporting a really weird issue. Using Microsoft Exchange 2007 OWA, when they are typing out a new e-mail, the font size will be what they have selected. However, as soon as they hit the Enter key, subsequent text that they type is suddenly and inexplicably at a smaller font size.

This is made worse (from a troubleshooting standpoint) in that it is intermittent, and only a few users have reported having the problem at all; I've so far been completely unable to reproduce the issue. Has anyone seen this kind of issue before? Or can anyone point me toward good troubleshooting steps to try and resolve this?

**Update:** I just found [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817314) that describes nearly-identical symptoms. Unfortunately, this one pertains to Exchange 2003, and following their description of the issue I couldn't replicate it. Still, maybe it will help someone else better understand what's going on, or help point someone (maybe even me!) toward the solution.

**Update 2:** Now I have found [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976794), which does in fact apply to Exchange 2007. However, I cannot replicate the issue as they describe, and I'm 99% sure that Update Rollup 2 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 2 has been applied to our server anyway (reinforced by the fact that I cannot replicate what's described here).

Comment: I'd look at the user's signature first and see if there is some font weirdness in there somewhere.

Comment: Do they all have something in common, such as a non-standard browser? If they're not already, I'd get them to try it out in Internet Explorer to try and rule out any browser-specific bug.

Comment: @Hyppy Already thought of that, and there's nothing "weird" that I can see. Some have a different font/size than they type messages in, but that doesn't seem to trigger the behavior. @Ben They're all using IE. A non-IE browser is forced to use OWA "Light", which lacks any font controls whatsoever.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I thought it was Exchange 2007 where some non-IE browsers got OWA Premium, but it was Exchange 2010. If you want me, I'll be in the corner with my dunce hat on :-)

Comment: I've seen similar problem before using chrome under linux. don't know a solution but thought maybe you can reproduce the problem using this environment